# Nested Javascript Loops producing strange result

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, for-loop, nested

So I'm trying to build an array via two "for" loops, one for each level of the multidimensional array.

Variables:

```
var pos = new Array();
var scales = [
  2,   // Background
  0.9, // Slide_1 (farthest back)
  1,   // Slide 2
  1.15 // Slide 3
];
```

Here is the code:

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  var nextPosition = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < numZones; i++) {
    alert(j + '' + i);
    pos[j][i] = nextPosition;
    nextPosition = (nextPosition + screenWidth + bufferSize) / scales[j];
  }
}
```

It will iterate through the first tier fine, but when it rolls over to the second tier, Firebug is throwing a vague error at the `pos[j][i] = nextPosition` line. It claims

```
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
```

Needless to say, I'm quite annoyed and perplexed. What exactly is undefined? What am I missing? I'm `alert()`ing the values of `i` and `j` on each pass, and they're fine with `i=0` and `j=1` but when it hits the above-mentioned line, it throws the error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you never define `pos[j]`. Thus, `pos[j][i]` is like `undefined[i]`. Try this:

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    var nextPosition = 0;
    pos[j] = [];                         <== new statement
    for(var i=0; i < numZones; i++) {
        alert(j + '' + i);
        pos[j][i] = nextPosition;
        nextPosition = (nextPosition + screenWidth + bufferSize) / scales[j];
    }
}
```

As an aside, I'd recommend initializing `pos` using an array literal:

```
var pos = [];
```

rather than with `new Array()`. It's considered more stylish. :)

Comment: I never would have thought of that. Thank you very much! I know it's just a computer, but I wish the Javascript debugger would've mentioned exactly which part was "undefined".